# How do I sort a string array alphabetically by length?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, lambda

By alphabetically by length I mean as follows:

given:
{ "=", "==>>", "=>>", "=>", "!>" }

I want to get out:

```
!>
=
=>
=>>
==>>
```

I'm currently just using OrderBy(x => x.Length).ToArray()

anyone got a better lambda?

Is this reasonably possible? lol, I'm not sure what the rule conventions here would be :-(

Comment: "Alphabetically by length" doesn't mean anything. You can sort alphabetically, or you can sort by length. Or, you can sort by one and then sort by the other when the first sort says that they're the same. In your example, you seem to be sorting exclusively alphabetically.

Comment: Can you explain why you want that result? Why would "!>" be before "=" eventhough it's longer?

Comment: Is what you really want, to sort alphabetically on the first character and then by length thereafter?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the application of this code?

Comment: @Josh command line prompts for different access levels, but i'm honestly just writing a "read until response is found" serial communications function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Writing your own string comparer you can do this, which meets both set of requirements you've posted.

```
    public class MyStringComparer : IComparer<string>
    {
        #region IComparer<string> Members

        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            if (x[0] == y[0])
            {
                return x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length);
            }
            else return x[0].CompareTo(y[0]);
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

a bcde bcd b bced cb

would yield:

a b bcd bcde bced cb

and { "=", "==>>", "=>>", "=>", "!>" }

yields:

```
!>
=
=>
=>>
==>>
```

by calling: `myStringCollection.OrderBy(x=>x, new MyStringComparer).ToArray();`

Comment: I don't see the point of creating a custom class here when lambda expressions can do the same thing more succinctly, as I demonstrate.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to sort by Alpha then by length, use the OrderBy and ThenBy methods:

```
var strings = new List<string> { "=", "==>>", "=>>", "=>", "!>" };
strings = strings.OrderBy( x => x ).ThenBy( x => x.Length ).ToList();
strings.ForEach( Console.WriteLine );
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using a list and I have been trying to search online for a solution for this. Nothing that i found worked for me. I decided to create a method that sorts the elements by length. To sort it first by alphabetical order I use a collection sort.

```
    subfolders.Sort();
    public void SortByLength(List<string> subfolders)
    {
        int l = 0;
        int l2 = 0;
        for (int i = subfolders.Count() - 1; i != 0; i--)
        {
            l = subfolders[i].Length;
            if (i != subfolders.Count() - 1 && l2 < l)
            {
                string folder = subfolders[i + 1];
                subfolders.RemoveAt(i + 1);
                subfolders.Insert(0, folder);
            }
            l2 = l;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following to sort the array. Here I am sorting the array with middle letter.
I think this will help.

```
string[] names = { "Rajeshwar","Raj", "Vijay", "Sunil","Dhiresh","Sonmani" };
names = names.OrderBy(x => x.Substring(x.Length/2,1)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear about your question, but it seems you want to sort *firstly by string length*, *then by alphabetical position*.

You could try this as a LINQ solution:

```
vals = vals.OrderBy(str => str.Length).ThenBy(str => str).ToArray();
```

If you want a (rather more efficient) solution that does not use LINQ (though still makes nice use of lambda expressions), you could try the following:

```
Array.Sort(vals, (strA, strB) =>
{
    var lengthComp = Comparer<int>.Default.Compare(strA.Length, strB.Length);
    if (lengthComp == 0)
        return string.Compare(strA, strB);
    return lengthComp;
});
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I tried `OrderBy(x => x)` with the test data that you provided, and that produces exactly the output that you want.

If it's an array that you have from start, you can just use the `Array.Sort` method:

```
Array.Sort(data);
```

Edit:
The above does not apply to the new data that you have put in the question. Awaiting a clarification about the data (as commented to the question).

Answer (score -4):

Using a standard string compare function for sorting should do exactly that.

strncmp() in C

String.compare() in C++

String.compareTo() in Java

all work for that purpose.

Comment: Well done for not only *not* answering the question but also providing examples in every mainstream C-style language *except* C#.